# X is a normal distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

$$X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
I need to find the variance of $Y=|X|$ and to determine its probability density function, as well as $E[Y]$.

I think that I need to use the formula $\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ so then I can write the pdf for Y as $$\varphi(|y|) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(|y|-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-y^2}$$

For $E[|Y|]$ I think it's useful that $E[X]=1$

Answer (score 1):

The CDF of $Y$ is computed as it follows :
$$
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) &= \mathbb{P}(Y = |X| \le y) \\
       &= \mathbb{P}(-y \le X \le y) \\
       &= F_X(y) - F_X(-y) \\
       &= \Phi(y) - (1 - \Phi(y)) \\
       &= 2\Phi(y) - 1
\end{align}
$$
In consequence, the PDF of $Y$ is given by
$$
f_Y(y) = F_Y'(y) = 2\phi(y) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}.
$$
This result is not surprising, since the absolute value in $Y = |X|$ acts by combining the events $\{X = x\}$ and $\{X = -x\}$.

Comment: Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

I know that for a real random variable $X$ with density $f(x)$ and a borelian function $h:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ when $h(x)\geq 0, \forall x \in \Bbb R$ we have
$$E[h(X)] = \int_\Bbb R h(x) f(x)dx$$
So in this case we have $h(x) = |x|$ and
$$E[Y] = E[|X|] = \int_\Bbb R |x|\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx= \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt\pi}$$
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I understand. It's very helpful!